# Spreading array to arguments in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an array of arrays, and I'd like to use each as arguments for a function, for instance, in javascript it could look like:

```js
const args = [
    [1, 'a'],
    [2, 'b'],
];

const concatter = (first, second) => `${first}-${second}`;

const test = args.map(a => concatter(...a));
console.dir(test);
```

I've tried something similar in typescript, but I'm having issues getting it to work. [Here's a link to the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20args%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B1%2C%20'a'%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B2%2C%20'b'%5D%2C%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20concatter%20%3D%20(first%3A%20number%2C%20second%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%60%24%7Bfirst%7D-%24%7Bsecond%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20singleTest%20%3D%20concatter(...args%5B0%5D)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20args.map(a%20%3D%3E%20concatter(...a))%3B) The code looks like this:

```
const args = [
    [1, 'a'],
    [2, 'b'],
];

const concatter = (first: number, second: string) => `${first}-${second}`;

const singleTest = concatter(...args[0]);
const test = args.map(a => concatter(...a));
```

However with this, the calls to `concatter` show the error:

`Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.`

It seems as though I'm making a fairly basic error here, but I haven't yet been able to find any information on what that might be.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd use spread in this situation. Since you *know* concatter requires two arguments, why not just `const test = args.map(([a,b]) => concatter(a, b));`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed I'd agree that that is a better solution, though I'm still interested in why spread doesn't work here

Comment: TypeScript doesn't appear to understand that the elements in `args` always have length 2, and as such will throw an error (since it assumes it could be of _any_ length, even zero).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to add a type for your args so TypeScript knows that the `args` variable is an array of tuples with a number and a string.

Then it will work:

```
const args: [number, string][] = [
    [1, 'a'],
    [2, 'b'],
];

const concatter = (first: number, second: string) => `${first}-${second}`;

const singleTest = concatter(...args[0]);

const test = args.map(a => concatter(...a));

console.log(test);
```

Comment: TypeScript's static analysis is amazingly deep. :-)

Comment: Fantastic, this works in the playground; however, for the code I'm working on, this doesn't work; I get the error `TS2556`, I believe the same as was on the playground, `Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.` I'm guessing this is to do with a typescript or tslint version?

Comment: @OliverRadini I think it might have been an issue in previous version of TypeScript. I tested with 3.4.2 and it works, but check out this issue on GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4130

Comment: @Daniel For reference, upgrading my typescript from `2.4.1` to `3.4.3` got this to work

Comment: Thanks man. This docs also helped me achieving that. https://auth0.com/blog/typescript-3-exploring-tuples-the-unknown-type/